# TextFied Expression: keep whitespaces at the end of a textfield

Tags: jasper-reports, whitespace, truncate

I'm having a problem in a report where I have a `$F{field}` in which you can receive a value with whitespaces at the end. Example :
 "20142101          ").
 
The textField must be horizontally align to "right".
 
The result in my PDF is "20142101" (the whitespaces doesn't appear)

The problem (I think) is that *JasperReports* automatically does a trim in the *textField* but I don't want this!

I've tried using options:

- Strech with overflow
- Print when detail overflows
- net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char = true
- net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text = true
- markup : none or html (with  tag)

but it doesn't work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me without trim the field's value. Can you post the full sample (with datasource) to reproduce your issue?

Comment: You can use `\t` for spacing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a borderless box with right/left padding for the textfields.

```
<textField>
<reportElement ../>
<box border="None" rightPadding="10"/>
<textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
<textFieldExpression..
```

[Source of info](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/505954/align-right-align-left-and-margin/)

Note, when I tried it out, my jasper studio editor turned the box element into the following but it has the same effect.

```
<textField>
      <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="233" y="0" width="303" height="18" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#817F82" uuid="501dc3cf-f3cf-45d4-aa25-de24c4100354"/>
      <box rightPadding="5">
        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
      </box>
     <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
       <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["My data where I want blank spaces in the end of this sentence.   "]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Works fine in a manually created template, without the <pen stuff. I manually create templates and run them through Java 8 using class net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimplePdfReportConfiguration. This is JR v6.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help !

I've found a solution which works but it's not very appropriate...

(My $F{field} is always a string of 60 characters)

```
($F{field} != null && $F{field}.length() == 60 && $F{field}.substring(59).equals(" ")) ? "<pre>"+$F{field}.substring(0,59)+"&nbsp</pre>" : $F{field}
```

(with markup html)

I will test with \t too.

Thx